Surjectiity of a conformal map
I'm stuck on this exercise:
Let $\left\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : z = x + iy, \; y > 0 \right\}$
Check whether the application $\phi : {\mathbb H}→ {\mathbb C}$ where ${\mathbb C}$
given
$\phi(z) = z^4 - z^2$
is conformal on the image. Find the 'image of φ. Hint: Factorize the application.
Using Freitag's conformal map definition I know that $\phi$ is not conformal where its derivative vanishes (in my case in $0,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, not included in my domain).
How can I prove what the image is in this case and also the surjectivty (cause solving $z^4-z^2=w$ sounds pretty labourous)?. I don't also understand the hint, thank you.

"Freitag's conformal map" isn't a very common name... at least in my country...

Welcome to MSE! <> If it matters, $z^4 - z^2 - w = 0$ can be solved with two applications of the quadratic formula.

the equation is easily factored as $(z^2-c_1(w))(z^2-c_2(w))=0$
